# Changing variable value throughout component when undefined

Tags: reactjs

How can i change a variable that is used all throughout a component when it is undefined?
For example:

```
<div>
 <div>{user.name}<div>
 <div>{user.id}<div>
<div>
```

If the state of the user is undefined how can i put another variable in it's place in both(or many) divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to conditionally check if your user object contains valid data; a very common situation which can be resolved with an `if` check.

Professionally I like to use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), which, as per MDN:

> returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

In your code, you would use it like this:

```
{user.name ?? fallbackVariable}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `variable` and then use that where ever you want in the `component` like below

```
const userObj = user ?? diffUser

<div>
 <div>{userObj?.name}<div>
 <div>{userObj?.id}<div>
<div>
```